# Wi-Fi Application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, wifi

HI

I am developing game in that I want to Play that game through Wi-Fi. So more that one

player can also play the game. I want to develop this game for iphone. I gone through WiTap

application which is on developer.apple.com since it's very hard to use. So if anybody knows
 how to send a simple data such as integer or string etc. through Wi-Fi for iphone to iphone.
Please help me to use simple application.
:)

Answer (score 2):

The iphone has basic Unix capability.  So simple sockets would work.

Here is a good starting point.

http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs460ta/cs460/labs/sockettutorial.html